# shellscript get column data

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a file that's the result of the comm command, it has 2 columns, I wish to separate these 2 columns into two different files, how do I do that?

the file looks like:

```
a
b
         g
         f
c
d
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on the column separator, you can do something like:

```
cut -f1 orig_file >file1
cut -f2 orig_file >file2
```

Here the column separator is supposed to be a TAB. If it is another character, you can use the `-d char` option to `cut`.

If you want to remove empty lines, as per your request, you can add to each line a `sed` command:

```
cut -f1 orig_file | sed -e /^$/d >file1
cut -f2 orig_file | sed -e /^$/d >file2
```

Comment: +1, cutting by field separators is best if the input file behaves that way

Comment: @Diego Sevilla, how do I remove the empty lines in the result files?

Answer (score 1):

Using `cut` will result in a command for each and every column.
You can do it using awk in a single command.

```
 awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i>i".txt"}' your_file
```

By default Tab  is the field separator.
Incase the field separator is other than tab,then add a flag after `awk` like below

```
awk -F"<field separator>" '{....
```

Answer (score 1):

You can cut the relevant parts based on character indexes:

```
# assuming constant 5 chars for col1, 5 chars for col2
cat file | cut -c0-5  | sed '/^\s*$/ {d}' > col1
cat file | cut -c6-10 | sed '/^\s*$/ {d}' > col2
```

The `sed` pipe removes empty lines (those with only whitespace). They can also be removed with `grep -v '^[[:space:]]*$'`.

Comment: @Diego: Sure, it's a matter of style. I find it nice to have all the manipulation in pipes.